# Set price value, whenever product is selected in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Rails newbie here. I am having issue with how to set default value for price.

Here's the code:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :customer_id, collection: Customer.all, %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :items do |i| %>
      <%= render 'item_fields', :f => i %>     
  <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ product, f, :items %>

<% end %>
```

partial _item_fields form:

```
<%= f.input :qty %>
<%= f.select :product_id, Product.all.map { |p| [p.name, p.id }, { include_blank: true } %>
<%= f.text_field :price %>
<%= link_to_remove_association image_tag("delete.png") %>
```

The plan is to set price value whenever product is selected so it can be saved. Was trying many ways with no luck.

Product table has name, price field.

I need your help to accomplish this.
What is the best way to do that? Ajax, javascript?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you select a product_id, a price gets set, without something being sent to the server? You need JavaScript/JQuery for that.

The rule is when you want something changed in real time without a visit back to the server, you use JavaScript. Something like `$('.product_id').on('change', function(){$('.price_field').value = $('.product_id').data('price')})` or something to that effect (a little rusty on the JQuery but I think things are manageable from here).

Comment: I finally get the onchange to work, but the {$('.price_field').value = $('.product_id').data('price')}) still could not make it work. I found another example that exactly work but somehow when I add it into js it won't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Normally there should be tests for that. But I haven't done JS tests yet so what I would do is to console.log stuff out in Chrome console so I can at least have an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Product.all.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id, {'data-price'=>p.price}]}
then you can access it through $('.product_id').data('price')

Comment: The new issue arise when its used on nested form.
I could not access it using $('.product_id').data('price').
I should use its id. (productselect). The thing is when I use its ID, whenever I add new product the price will be all the same as first product selected.